# can i sum of values that has the same key in dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this :

```
let dic: KeyValuePairs = ["foo":2,"bar":3,"bat":5, "foo":5,"bat":7,"bar":5]
```

I want the sum of values that has the same key.

The output should look like this:

`["foo":7, "bar":8, "bat":12]`

Comment: Don’t dictionary keys need to be unique?

Comment: @esqew KeyValuePairs can have duplicates

Comment: Don't say "dictionary" when you mean "KeyValuePairs." The former requires unique keys, while the latter does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyValuePairs` responds to `reduce` so you can do this

```
let dic: KeyValuePairs = ["foo":2,"bar":3,"bat":5, "foo":5,"bat":7,"bar":5]

let result : [String:Int] = dic.reduce(into: [:]) { (current, new) in
    current[new.key] = new.value + (current[new.key] ?? 0)
}
```

Comment: @Caleb  Yes, I did.

Comment: yes, I run the code and it's working what I want

Comment: @JanmejayYadav you can use Dictionary Key-based subscript default value `let result  = dic.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key, default: 0] += $1.value }`